# Python, select a specific line

Tags: python

I want to read a textfile using python and print out specific lines. The problem is that I want to print a line which starts with the word "nominal" (and I know how to do it) and the line following this which is not recognizable by some specific string. Could you point me to some lines of code that are able to do that?

Comment: show us your code so far, what have you attempted

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: > Could you point me to some lines of code that are able to do that?  < Yes: https://github.com/ranxian/rate3/blob/d226de257360a477b0958ec0a22b4b201a2b8b65/tools/cpp/test/convert.py#L5

Comment: This is very straightforward. It seems like homework. Why should we do your homework for you?

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman for your very kind reply. It's not homework, it's for my work and it is very important, I'm new in python

Comment: Okay -- but you in general will get more immediate (and more helpful) answers if you show some work.

Answer (score 0):

In good faith and under the assumption that this will help you start coding and showing some effort, here you go:

```
file_to_read = r'myfile.txt'

with open(file_to_read, 'r') as f_in:
    flag = False
    for line in f_in:
        if line.startswith('nominal'):
            print(line)
            flag = True
        elif flag:
            print(line)
            flag = False
```

it might work out-of-the-box but please try to spend some time going through it and you will definitely get the logic behind it. Note that text comparison in `python` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too large, you can put it all in a list:

```
def printLines(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = f.read().split('\n')
        if len(lines) == 0: return None
        if lines[0].startswith('Nominal'): print(lines[0])
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[1:]):
            if lines[i-1].startswith('Nominal') or line.startswith('Nominal'):
                print(line)
```

Then e.g. `printLines('test.txt')` will do what you want.